# Very strange jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL error

Tags: angular, phantomjs, protractor

I'm trying to run some e2e tests using `protractor` and `phantomjs`.
When I run the test I get the error:

```
- Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

The test is:

```
import { browser, element, by } from 'protractor';

describe('example test', () => {

  it('stupid test', () => {
    console.log('in test');
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });    

});
```

Any idea what the problem is ? any help is welcomed :)

Comment: Try to set `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 3000`

Comment: It is set in the protractor.conf.js

`  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    isVerbose: true,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function () { }
  },`  

But it still fails.

Comment: Please let us know if you solved this problem

Answer (score 1):

For me (using karma), the specified port in the Karma config file did not match up with the specified port in the protractor config file.

```
exports.config = {
...,
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9876/',//<--This port should match the port in your Karma (test runner) config file
framework: 'jasmine',
jasmineNodeOpts: {
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 3000,
  print: function() {}
}
```

This answer seemed obvious after I found it, but the ports had gotten changed in source control and the fix wasn't immediately apparent.

Answer (score -1):

you are missing callback in your test

```
return expect(true).toBe(true);
```

(or)

call `callback()` when all your steps are completed like

```
 it('stupid test', (callback) => {
    console.log('in test');
    expect(true).toBe(true);
    callback();
  });
```

(or)

```
 it('stupid test', (done) => {
    console.log('in test');
    expect(true).toBe(true);
    done();
  });
```

Comment: You should not need to return anything in a synchronous test.